# Find the 2nd and 4th saturday for a month to check for bank holiday in go

Tags: date, go, google-app-engine-golang

I want to find the 2nd and 4th saturday for a month to check bank holiday. I have added check for sundays for now. Currently this how my function looks with date as input in implemented in Go

```
func IsHoliday(date time.Time) bool {
    return date.Weekday() == time.Sunday
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how implemented function find alternate saturdays. It finds the first saturday date, then compares the input date with 2nd and 4th saturdays.

```
func isAlternateSaturday(date time.Time) bool {
    firstDateOfMonth := time.Date(date.Year(), date.Month(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil)
    firstSaturday := (6-int(firstDateOfMonth.Weekday())) + firstDateOfMonth.Day()
    return (date.Day() == firstSaturday + 7) || (date.Day() == firstSaturday + 21)
}
```

Then integrated it with main IsHoliday function:

```
func IsHoliday(date time.Time) bool {
    return date.Weekday() == time.Sunday || isAlternateSaturday(date)
}
```